# Unmarshaling viper config into another viper config

Tags: go, viper-go

I have a viper config that has some fixed fields, and some dynamic fields. It looks like this:

```
//always contains those keys
a: 1
b: "2"
c: true
//those keys might change:
params:
  x1: 111
  x2: "222"
```

I know I can unmarshal the `params` part into a `map[string]interface{}` and use the values at runtime, but I would like to unmarshal this config into the a viper config instead, ie the struct should look like this:

```
type Config struct {
   A int              `mapstructure:"a"`
   B string           `mapstructure:"b"`
   C bool             `mapstructure:"c"`
   Params viper.Viper `mapstructure:"params"`
}
```

but when trying to use the struct like that, the `Params` variable is unmarshaled into an empty config.

Can viper support such usage?

Comment: That's not how viper works. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have many components, and I select at runtime what component to use. each component have different config values